# Marshal C++ wchar_t** in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net, marshalling

In C++ library code I have:

```
bool __stdcall functionName(const wchar_t** fileNames)
```

In my C# program this function must get an array of string (filenames).
How do I call it in C#?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try P/Invoke with a `string[]` parameter? And how do you pass the size of the array?

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski yes, I try it. I get the error message about unbalanced stack. The function has another parameter "size_t namesCount", which transmits the size of the array. I just tried to simplify the question :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify the marshalling explicitely:

```
[DllImport("mylibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
static extern bool functionName(
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray, ArraySubType = UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] string[] fileNames,
    int length);
```